# kafka partition has lots of log segments

Tags: apache-kafka

One topic has 20 partitions, almost everyone has more than 20,000 log segment files, most of them are created months ago. Even after I config the `retention.ms` to very short, the segments are not deleted. While other topics can recycle normal.

I am wondering what's the issue inside, and how to solve it. Because I'm worry about the number of total segments will keep increasing  that larger than OS `vm.max_map_count`, which will damage kafka process itself. Following image is the describe about the abnormal topic.

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `log.retention.check.interval.ms`? Also, have you set `log.cleanup.policy` to `cmpact` or `delete`?

Comment: log.retention.check.interval.ms is 300000, other topics can deleted log normally. And log.cleanup.policy is the default value, which should be 'delete'.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the issue is exactly, but some things to consider:

- **Broker vs topic-specific configs.** Check to make sure your topic actually has the configs you think it has, and is not inheriting them from the broker settings.
- **Configs related to `retention`.** As mentioned by Girogos Myrianthous, you can look at `log.retention.check.interval.ms` and `log.cleanup.policy`. I would also look at the roll related settings, like `log.roll.hours`. I believe that in some cases, Kafka will not delete a segment until its partition rolls, even if the segment is old. And rolling follows the following behavior:

> The log rolling time is no longer depending on log segment create time. Instead it is now based on the timestamp in the messages. More specifically. if the timestamp of the first message in the segment is T, the log will be rolled out when a new message has a timestamp greater than or equal to T + log.roll.ms (http://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html)

So make sure to consider the record timestamps, not just the segment files' age.

Finally:

- What version of Kafka are you using?
- Have you looked carefully at the broker logs? Broker logs is how I've solved all such problems that I've encountered.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.   
The Kafka version is 0.10.2 

**  I have check the config inside zookeeper about the abnormal topic, which I suppose is override broker configs.  There are two configuration: `retention.ms=1000`, `segment.ms=15000`

** And `log.retention.check.interval.ms` and `log.cleanup.policy` are working, because other topics are recycle normally. 
And I checked the broker logs, but can not find any useful information. Again, thanks for your reply!

Comment: You’re welcome. Please post an answer if you figure it out. These issues can be frustrating sometimes